# Angular 5 web server with only internal access allowed

Tags: node.js, webserver, angular5

Does someone knows how to consume a internal webserver with Angular 5? I have a NodeJS server side application with only internal access allowed, so I can't consume that by client side. I thought to make a NodeJS application to be like a Facade layer, but the best would be to have all the http calls running in only one port. If someone can help me I really thanks.

Comment: I've solved the problem using Angular Universal

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to run an application gateway on the same server as the *internal webserver* and configure the gateway accordingly.

Some options:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy (a simple NodeJS solution)
- https://github.com/Netflix/zuul (more configurable / complex Java solution)

Comment: Thanks Chris, but with this both solutions the requests continue coming from the client side.

Comment: Right, the gateway application receives the request from the client and then connects on to the internal service. Both should work, assuming you configure them to connect to the internal service on a loopback address. Unless you're saying the internal webserver has a security layer that inspects the client request params to enforce local access only, which even on that case, you can fake the headers in the gateway